# scrollview extending to whole layout

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a layout as below

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView>
      <LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is to divide the screen into half showing graph at one half of the screen and the report at the other half which alone i wish to be scrollable.

UPDATE

Please find the xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android=""
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#888888" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor=""
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:orientation="vertical" />  

<LinearLayout
    android:id=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"            
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_status"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src=""
            android:id=""
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <edu.apollogrp.android.widget.ProgressCircle
            android:id=""
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progressDrawable=""
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src=""
            android:id=""
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight=""
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

               <TextView
                android:id="@
                android:textColor="@color/grades_green"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
               <TextView
                android:id="@
                android:textColor=""
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">  </TextView>                  
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/grades_green"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >    
            </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:fillViewport="false"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"     
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

but the whole layout is scrollable now :(
Is there any way i can make only half the screen scrollable?
PS: android:fillViewport is set to false

**UPDATE**

I found out why the scroll is not working. it was because the scroll was inside a pull to refresh list view. :(
Looking for a work around for that now

Comment: Plz provide your compelete Xml layout

Comment: try this in linear layout.
<LinearLayout
       android:scrollbars="vertical" 
></LinearLayout>

Comment: instead of using relative use linearlayout

Comment: @GirishBhutiya not working :(

Comment: @Preethi SHOW YOUR XML CODE FOR BETTER SUGGESTIONS

Comment: @Preethi SHOW YOUR XML CODE FOR BETTER SUGGESTIONS –

Comment: @Preethi .. DO ONE THING.. CREATE ONE MORE CHILD LINEARLAYOUT IN SCROLLVIEW. I.E. scrollview -> linearlayout -> linearlayout -> your stuffs.. have you tried like this.. ??

Comment: @TechEnd it doesnt work..

Comment: @Preethi : set android:layout_weight of scrollview to 1

Comment: @Deepthi it doesnt work and i dont want the screen to be divided to half either.

Comment: @Preethi .. try some other way.. creating two linear layout. put relative in one n scrollview in another. divide them properly

Comment: which side of screen you want to be scrollable ? at this moment, is your right side of the screen is scrollable ? or right and left both side is scrollable ? @Preethi

Comment: yes, only the right side is scrollable, i want only the layout inside the scrollview to be scrollable rather than the whole screen

Comment: i have posted an answer .. try that and let me know what happen. @Preethi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll view was not working because it was inside a list view that implements the pull to refresh.. Hence the layout changes dont effect.

Sorry everyone, thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: u have given the `xml` code in your question, right?? now, plz can you tell or show us where is the `<ListView>` in your given `xml` code ?? thankx

Comment: this xml file is included in another xml, basically the whole page is under the PullToRefresh List view, and hence the issue.

Comment: then, you should have been classified that before.

Comment: yup,really sorry.. but i was bug fixing, and wasnt aware of the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the layout_weight attribute to divide the screen.

```
 <LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="1">
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView android:layout_weight="1">
  <LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the width attribute has already been set to 0dp so that the weight would take effect

Comment: sorry. typo mistake it should weight not width

Comment: still no need to suffix `dp` you have to give direct value and also `layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: still `try to put weight attribute to divide the screen, instead width attribute`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_weight`, here is sample code

```
 <LinearLayout>
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show me your full xml code & screenshots of current display view

Comment: there are too much error in your xml, first correct it & edit your question

Comment: I can't solved all error here.. plz show me perfect code for solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parentt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    ////// Your left side layout content /////////      

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"     
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            >

            <TextView
                android:id=""
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i did try wrapping the scroll view inside a linear layout, but it didnt make any difference. the scroll view should just have a child right, then why this difference in behaviour :(

Comment: put your left side screen's content in the upper `<LinearLayout>` i have write in the answer & put your right side `scrollview` in the down `<LinearLayout>` as i described in the answer. it should work , because i write this and run this and it works. so try like the answer. @Preethi